# how can get part of link very important

Tags: javascript

how can i get from this link http://127.0.0.1:4000/resetPassword/3067a7a5b300f90ee593508647a7dbf7aa38a47b15808e69aa8b5421ea0f1408 the number after resetPassword/
can any one help me??

Comment: Try using `new URL(yourUrl)`.  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL  You may also need [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/resetPassword/3067a7a5b300f90ee593508647a7dbf7aa38a47b15808e69aa8b5421ea0f1408';

const regex = /(?<=resetPassword\/).+/;
const result  = str.match(regex);
console.log(result?.[0]);
```